# Prevent to access local filesystem in Domino server

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

We need to prevent the access to Windows local filesystem through an XAgent in a Domino Server:

```
  xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:

  [...]

  var url = new java.net.URL("D:\path\to\archive.pdf");

  var conn:java.net.HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection();

  [...]
```

¿Should we have to do at Domino-level or Windows-level?

Comment: Domino will only serve files through http that are inside (or below) the [dominodata]/domino/html directory. Did you actually try your code?

Comment: Yes, this code works on a 9.01 FP8 Domino and an anonymouse user can reach to the shared files ("D:\...\...")

Comment: Do you want this specific xagent to not run that code part if the user is anonymous? Or do you want to ensure that any existing and future code can not access the file system?

Comment: the second, not to expose the local filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

You can disallow access to the file system by changing the java policy file (java.pol). Something like this:

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Notes\\*", "read";
};
```

This blocks every access to the filesystem and only allows that files in the Notes directory can be read.

See: [Permissions in the Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html)